# ImportError: cannot import name 'logsumexp' when importing sklearn.model_selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was trying to import `sklearn.model_selection` with Jupiter Notebook under anaconda environment with python 3.5, but I was warned that I didn't have "model_selection" module, so I did `conda update scikit-learn`.

After that, I received a message of `ImportError: cannot import name 'logsumexp'` when importing `sklearn.model_selection`.

I reinstalled `sklearn` and `scipy`, but still received the same error message. May I have some advice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came across exactly the same problem just now. After I updated `scikit-learn` and tried to `import sklearn.model_selection`, the ImportError appeared.

I just restarted anaconda and ran it again.

It worked. Don't know why.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem with the same way. I updated sklearn and anaconda, the problem still occurred. But when I restart anaconda and Jupyter, it worked. My friend had the same issue, she restarted Jupiter and solved the issue. It feels like an issue with robustness of Jupyter with Sklearn, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best solution, but rolling back to 0.18.2 worked for me (after trying all above-mentioned solutions):

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn==0.18.2
```

Ultimately, it worked with version 0.18.2 of scikit-learn and version 1.2.0 of scipy.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error. I am using Anaconda. 
Updating every involved package via `pip` and `conda` solved the problem.

```
pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
pip install scipy --upgrade
pip install sklearn --upgrade
```

and

```
conda update scikit-learn
conda update scipy
```

Answer (score 1):

The same error appeared when I tried to import hmm from hmmlearn, I reinstalled scipy and it worked. Hope this can be helpful.(I have tried updating all of the packages involved to solve the problem, but did not work. My computer system is ubuntu 16.04, with anaconda3 installed.)

Answer (score 0):

Just closed the Spyder editor and restarted. This Issue got fixed.