# ImportError: cannot import name 'logsumexp' from 'scipy.misc' (C:\Users\firstname.lastname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py)

Tags: python, scipy, package, conda

I'm trying to `import hmm` with jupyter notebook under anaconda env with python 3.
I tried to update the packages with the following commands,

```
pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
pip install scipy --upgrade
pip install sklearn --upgrade
```

But still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Show the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message).  There is useful information in there, including the exact line that raises the error.  The function `logsumexp` used to be `scipy.misc`, but that was deprecated quite a while ago, and now `logsumexp` is in `scipy.special`.  So either your code or one of your dependencies needs to be updated to use the new location.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037903/importerror-cannot-import-name-logsumexp-when-importing-sklearn-model-selecti

Answer (score 1):

do this

`from scipy.special import logsumexp`